# react native position absolute is hiding the text

Tags: react-native

after tried almost each and everything from the stackoverflow , github i am not able to fix this issue 
after giving position: 'absolute' my text is hidden that is my code

```
    import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const userMain = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>user homepage here</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
                <Text style={styles.btnText}> Text </Text> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        position:'relative',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    btn: {
        width: null, height:null, zIndex: 0, position: 'absolute',  top: 0, bottom:0, left:0, right:0
    },
    btnText: {
        fontSize: 50,
        color: 'black',
        zIndex:99
    }

})

export default userMain
```

I have given parent container position relative as well , tried zindex as well but no luck

> (testing on android emulator)

Comment: `width: null, height:null` might be a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code and use `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` instead of `react-native-gesture-handler`

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
//import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const userMain = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>user homepage here</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
                <Text style={styles.btnText}> Text </Text> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        position:'relative',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    btn: {
        width: null, height:null, zIndex: 0, position: 'absolute',  top: 0, bottom:0, left:0, right:0
    },
    btnText: {
        fontSize: 50,
        color: 'black',
        zIndex:99
    }

})

export default userMain
```

[image]

Comment: awesome :) fixed